# WatchKit - Force Touch API Questions

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, force-touch, taptic-engine

Some questions to the Force Touch Menu:

1. Now when I perform a Force Touch and press one of my menu Items, the whole InterfaceController, where my Menu is implemented is loading new. 
   Is this avoidable?
2. I've implemented a menu with 4 menuItems for my InterfaceController.

With one of this menuItems, I want to enable/disable the haptic Feedback of my Buttons.

My button methods are like this:

```
- (IBAction) but1Pressed {
       [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticType.Click];
       // Do something
}
```

How can I disable the TapticEngine, if the user disables it ind the ForceTouchMenu?

Comment: question 3: is it possible to simulate the haptic feedback in watch simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, as by today that's **not** possible.
2. If I understand you properly, you need a `BOOL` which defines whether the app should perform haptic feedback when a button in your interface controller is being pressed.

To realise that, implement the following:

```
BOOL shouldGiveTapticFeedback = YES
```

Then you need a method to change this `BOOL` when the corresponding menu item is being pressed:

```
- (IBAction) tapticFeedbackChangeButtonPressed {

   //change BOOL value

   shouldGiveTapticFeedback = !shouldGiveTapticFeedback

}
```

Finally, you need to check whether the taptic feedback should be played, when a button in your interface controller is being pressed:

```
- (IBAction) interfaceButtonPressed {

   if(shouldGiveTapticFeedback) {

      //play sound

      [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticType.Click];

   }
}
```

3. No, that's **not** possible either.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I've made it the same way with an boolean value :)´